# In a CV, Should I write exact programming languages name (Python, Java, C, ...) or regroup them as categories (object oriented, procedural, ...)?

Tags: resume

I am doing my last year in high school and next year, I'll need to get my first job while doing my studies. I learned some languages by myself.

In my CV, should I write "Python", "Java", "C", etc... as skills or should I write "Object Oriented Programming", "Procedural Programming", etc... ?

Thanks.

Comment: Bear in mind that almost all (IMOE) programming job adverts will specify exactly what languages are currently in use. In that sense, would it be helpful to the employer to know exactly where your experience lies?

Comment: I'm not replying to any job adverts, I had done an internship in that society, I contacted the person that was with me during this internship to ask about my first job (which is going to be linked with my studies) and they asked me a CV for it. That's why I'm asking how should I write it ?

Comment: It's different, he's talking about how to place it on his paper, my question is about regrouping or not languages in big ideas.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

List the languages - while it's not necessarily relevant for the one you're applying for here the convention is to list the individual technologies and this is how job specs are generally written so it will better allow people to match your CV to opportunities and also for people reviewing your CV to see if you have the skills they are looking for.

Answer (score 8):

The person in HR reading (skimming) your CV has no idea what Object Oriented Programming is, so they will throw you CV out because it doesn’t mention C++, Java and OOP which are all required. You didn’t mention OOP only some strange programming thing they never heard of.

I hope that makes it clear: Match their keywords.

Comment: More and more often, the person skimming that PC isn't a person, but some software making a first pass triage. That's why the last part of my CV is actually labelled "buzzwords, for scanning software" (and, so far, no one has mentioned it to me at interview). In any case, definitely game names of everything, and acronyms, and if there are alternatives (like ADA 95, ADA95), try to use all variants; a persona is unlikely to notice, but a program will (I like to play the percentages ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What I do on my resume is both: I have one line for specific languages, and one line for more general programming skills.

Employers are often looking for experience in specific languages, and much less often looking for general OO or procedural language experience. Listing the specific languages you know will be more useful to potential employers.